# CloudFlare redirect to certain port

Tags: redirect, dns, debian, vps, cloudflare

I've got a VPS running on Debian 8 where I have a few of Django apps that runs on `http://[IPv6]:8000` and `http://[IPv6]:8080` and I want to make CloudFlare DNS system to redirect from `http://www.example.com` to one of these addresses on different port than 80. Redirect to `http://[IPv6]` is ok, but when I try to redirect to different port, it throws an error.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can try SRV records, however Cloudflare won't proxy very many ports.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-